# Android pixelation of HTML5 canvas

Tags: android, canvas, rendering

I have a really weird effect happening on Android using an HTML5 canvas. Here is the code in question, it is using is the quadratic curve:

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.strokeStyle = wave.stroke;
ctx.moveTo(wave.sx, wave.sy);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(
  wave.x, wave.y,
  wave.ex, wave.ey
);
ctx.stroke();
```

And it draws upon itself multiple times:
http://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/9f899c4c64ab49113988055432b11a6b

Here it is on an iPhone:

[image: iPhone version]

But here it is on Android:

[image: Android version]

I'm saying Android but I've heard it's super smooth on a Galaxy S6.

Just as a side note I'm not very familiar with graphics (i.e. GPU etc) in general so a bit sure of what terms I should even be Googling – so please be gentle if you have any obvious solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're seeing are [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing) artefacts. The curve covers less than a pixel and for some reason, the rasterization might completely miss some of these. This seems to be explicitly when drawing quadratic curves while lines and even beziers seem to work fine for me, so you could approximate them with these.